# First Graph Adjacency List

Tags: c++, linked-list, graph

First time implementing a adjacency list. Is the use of exceptions correct? If anyone could test/read the code and give some advice on improvments I would appreciate it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <exception>
#include <list>

class VertexInvalidArg : public std::invalid_argument
{
public:
    VertexInvalidArg(const std::string &msg)
        :invalid_argument(msg)
    {}
};

class VertexUnderFlow : public std::underflow_error
{
public:
    VertexUnderFlow(const std::string &msg)
        :underflow_error(msg)
    {}
};

class Graph
{
public:
    Graph(int defaultVertices = 0);

    void addEdge(int v1, int v2);
    void addVertex();
    size_t noOfVertices() const;
    bool isEdge(int v1, int v2) const;
    bool isVertex(int v1) const;
    void clear();

private:
    std::vector<std::list<int> > adjList;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Graph& g);

    size_t vertexCount;
};

Graph::Graph(int defaultVertices)
{
    if (defaultVertices <= 0)
    {
        defaultVertices = 0;
    }
    vertexCount = defaultVertices;

    for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++)
    {
        std::list<int> vertex;
        adjList.push_back(vertex);
    }
}

void Graph::addVertex()
{
    std::list<int> vertex;
    adjList.push_back(vertex);
    ++vertexCount;
}

size_t Graph::noOfVertices() const
{
    return vertexCount;
}

void Graph::addEdge(int v1, int v2)
{
    if (v1 == v2)
    {
        throw VertexInvalidArg("Vertex Cannot Connect To Itself");
    }
    else if (v1 > vertexCount - 1 || v2 > vertexCount - 1)
    {
        throw VertexInvalidArg("Vertex Does Not Exist");
    }
    else
    {
        std::list<int>::iterator itr = adjList[v1].begin();
        while (itr != adjList[v1].end())
        {
            if (*itr == v2)
            {
                throw VertexInvalidArg("Edge Already Exists");
            }
            ++itr;
        }

        adjList[v1].push_back(v2);
        adjList[v2].push_back(v1);
    }
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Graph& g)
{
    if (g.vertexCount == 0)
    {
        throw VertexUnderFlow("No Vertices to Display");
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < g.vertexCount; i++)
    {
        os << "Vertex " << i << " Connects To Vertex: ";
        std::list<int>::const_iterator itr = g.adjList[i].begin();
        while (itr != g.adjList[i].end())
        {
            os << *itr << " ";
            ++itr;
        }
        os << std::endl;
    }
    return os;
}

bool Graph::isEdge(int v1, int v2) const
{
    if (vertexCount == 0)
    {
        throw VertexUnderFlow("Graph is empty");
    }
    else if (v1 == v2)
    {
        throw VertexInvalidArg("Vertex Cannot Connect To Itself");
    }
    else if (v1 > vertexCount - 1 || v2 > vertexCount - 1)
    {
        throw VertexInvalidArg("Vertex Does Not Exist");
    }

    bool found = false;
    std::list<int>::const_iterator itr = adjList[v1].begin();
    while (itr != adjList[v1].end())
    {
        if (*itr == v2)
        {
            found = true;
        }
        ++itr;
    }
    return found;
}

bool Graph::isVertex(int v1) const
{
    bool found = false;
    if (v1 < vertexCount)
    {
        found = true;
    }
    return found;
}

void Graph::clear()
{
    adjList.clear();
    vertexCount = 0;
}

int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::cin;
    using std::endl;


    Graph myG;
    int loop = 0;
    int menuChoice = 0;
    int V1 = 0, V2 = 0;

    while (loop != -1)
    {
        cout << "Please select operation: " << endl << endl;
        cout << "1: Add Vertex" << endl;
        cout << "2: Add Edge" << endl;
        cout << "3: Display Graph" << endl;
        cout << "4: Number of Vertices" << endl;
        cout << "5: Is Edge" << endl;
        cout << "6: Is Vertex" << endl;
        cout << "7: Clear" << endl;
        cout << "-1: Terminate Program" << endl << endl;

        cin >> menuChoice;
        switch (menuChoice)
        {
        case 1:
            myG.addVertex();
            cout << endl << "Vertex " << myG.noOfVertices() - 1 << " Added" << endl << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << endl << "Enter First Vertex: ";
            cin >> V1;
            cout << "Enter Second Vertex: ";
            cin >> V2;
            try
            {
                myG.addEdge(V1, V2);
            }
            catch (const VertexInvalidArg& e)
            {
                std::cerr << "Error: Invalid Argument: " << e.what();
            }
            cout << endl << "Edge between " << V1 << " and " << V2 << " Added";
            cout << endl << "Edge between " << V2 << " and " << V1 << " Added" << endl << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << endl;
            try
            {
                cout << myG;
            }
            catch (const VertexUnderFlow& e)
            {
                std::cerr << "Error: Under Flow: " << e.what();
            }
            cout << endl << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << endl << "Number of Vertices: ";
            cout << myG.noOfVertices();
            cout << endl << endl;
            break;
        case 5:
            cout << endl << "Enter First Vertex: ";
            cin >> V1;
            cout << "Enter Second Vertex: ";
            cin >> V2;
            cout << endl;
            try
            {
                cout << "Is Edge: " << myG.isEdge(V1, V2);
            }
            catch (const VertexInvalidArg& e)
            {
                std::cerr << "Error: Invalid Argument: " << e.what();
            }
            catch (const VertexUnderFlow& e)
            {
                std::cerr << "Error: Under Flow: " << e.what();
            }
            cout << endl << endl;
            break;
        case 6:
            cout << endl << "Enter Vertex: ";
            cin >> V1;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Is Vertex: " << myG.isVertex(V1);
            cout << endl << endl;
            break;
        case 7:
            cout << endl << "Graph Cleared" << endl << endl;
            myG.clear();
            break;
        case -1:
            cout << endl << "Operation Terminated";
            loop = -1;
            break;
        default: cout << endl << "Invalid Input" << endl << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << endl << endl;
    system("pause"); // TESTING
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Data Members**

You currently have two members:

```
std::vector<std::list<int> > adjList;
size_t vertexCount;
```

But `vertexCount` is always the size of `adjList`. That's just extra stuff you have to keep track of. The best thing you can say about it is that it's error prone. You can drop `vertexCount` and rewrite `size()` to simply be:

```
size_t Graph::noOfVertices() const
{
    return adjList.size();
}
```

Secondly, you implemented `adjList` as a `vector` of `list`s. That may be canonically correct, but `list` is actually not a good data structure for this since `list`s are very inefficient at iteration you do in several places. `vector` would be strictly better, due to its cache friendliness.

**Constructor**

The whole point of your constructor is to make `defaultVertices` empty lists. There is a constructor on `vector` which takes a size. Use it:

```
Graph::Graph(int defaultVertices)
: adjList(std::max(defaultVertices, 0))
{ }
```

Quite a bit cleaner!

**addVertex()**

If you can use C++11, you can rewrite this function as a one-liner as well:

```
adjList.emplace_back();
```

That will default-construct a new container in place as the new last element: exactly what you want. And note that we're not keeping track of `vertexCount` manually anymore - so don't have to do that either!

**addEdge()**

Is there a reason you're not supporting self-edges?

Your check against the max is correct, but weird. Better to do:

```
v1 >= adjList.size() || v2 >= adjList.size()
```

Any extra operations you add on your code make it harder to understand. The `-1`s here are just unnecessary.

Now for the main part of the function. You are looking for `v2` in `adjList[v1]`. There's an algorithm for that, it's called [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and it's a lot easier to use:

```
auto it = std::find(adjList[v1].begin(), adjList[v1].end(), v2);
if (it == adjList[v1].end()) {
    adjList[v1].push_back(v2);
    adjList[v2].push_back(v1);
}
else {
    // throw
}
```

**isEdge()**

Similarly, use `find()`. Here it's especially useful as it'll be much more efficient. Once you find your edge, you don't have to keep going - but you still do! The end could just be:

```
return std::find(adjList[v1].begin(), adjList[v1].end(), v2)
      != adjList[v1].end();
```

**isVertex()**

What you wrote is an antipattern. Anytime you want to check if an expression is true or false, you want to simply do:

```
return v1 < vertexCount;
```

Not:

```
return (v1 < vertexCount) ? true : false;
```

Not:

```
if (v1 < vertexCount) return true;
else return false;
```

Not what you did with the extra member variable. It's unnecessarily verbose and just looks funny.

**Redundancy**

You are keeping track of twice as much information as you need to. You have an edge from 2 to 5 *and* 5 to 2. If you are just keeping an adjacency list in an undirected graph, you can just keep the upper triangle. Add a helper to put the vertices in the correct order:

```
void sort(int& v1, int& v2) {
    if (v1 > v2) {
        std::swap(v1, v2);
    }
}
```

And then start each of your methods with a call to `sort()`, and only add and check the edges against `v1`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks! I've made all the changes and changed it to a vector of vectors! I had to change the sort functions return type to void and v1 < v2 so I could check against v1, now all working like clockwork! Appreciate it! I gather the exceptions are ok?